# Java RMI server call another RMI server

Tags: rmi

is it possible to have a RMI server where I can call another RMI server?  I want to have a client to connect to first RMI server, get some data and send  the data to second RMI server, which insert data to DB?

Comment: Of course, just write the appropriate client code in the first server.

Comment: and include it in the rmi server component or program you are trying to access from your main client(application connecting to the first rmi server)

Comment: @Acewin That's what 'in the first server' means.

Comment: yes so ??. @EJP

Comment: @Acewin So everything after 'and' in your comment is redundant. 'And' implies you are adding something. You weren't.

Comment: got your point. Did not pay much heed to the contextual usage of English. And yes apart from the usage of words both the comments are same. :P

Comment: Do you mean that I can have server class and inside client code to connect to another RMI sever?

Comment: Yes. Typically speaking you are working with java. when you are running a server you will definitely have some code getting executed in the server to  process the incoming request. This client piece for the next server would go there.